# How use pipe character inside Examples table of Behave test .feature file?

Tags: python-behave

I have a Behave Scenario outline where I need to use pipe character - `|` as a cell value inside Examples table. But I don't know how to escape this character to not be treated as column separator. I'm getting `Malformed table` error when I try to use `\|` sequence.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, it is not possible to escape cell delimiters as of version 1.2.5 (current at the time of posting). The relevant code is [in the `action_table` method](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/81aaea0d054aab5a9f2e6347b47d0a130fe1816f/behave/parser.py#L423). This is how it splits a line into cells:

```
cells = [cell.strip() for cell in line.split('|')[1:-1]]
```

I searched before and after this line but did not see code that would transform sequences like `\|` or anything similar into something that `.split('|')` would not affect.

The only solution I see, as of 1.2.5, would be to hand-code the content of your cells so that you use another character than `|` in the cell data and then convert it to `|` in your Python code. For instance, using `!`, you could have in the feature file:

```
| foo!bar |
```

and then convert `!` to `|` in your step implementations. This is awful but I don't see another way to get what you want.

Comment: Yes, it's ugly, but at least it's some solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Support to escaped pipes have been added: https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/1c6197b35c15e07b5bae62b3131a98f9caa88f4e/behave/parser.py#L701

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).